# How can I add Buttons to my bot page in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

So how do I add this button?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOXx3.png)
Thanks in advice

i tried it with `Client.change_presence(activity=discord... , buttons=["Website"])`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Discord (and subsequently the discord.py lib) does not have ways for us developers to modify those buttons. Both of those buttons are fairly new to Discord anyways. The button you were seeing is related to the bot "streaming  on Twitch" (ie Twitch integration) This is autogenerated for anyone who streams on Twitch with their account linked, and as such pops up for bots as well.

Your best bet would be to read update patch notes and keep an eye out for if they make that available to us devs at some point.

If you're looking for a subtle way to link a website to your bot, I would personally suggest using what Discord's API does offer: embeds. You can always include a link inside of the embed, or even put the website in the footer. Embeds are very versatile, and hopefully, you can use them to solve the issue you're running into.